# How to use a dartscript on your website

Tags: html, dart, dart2js

Hello i just started to learn some dart and im new in this forum aswell,

i've created the ubersimple webapp, with webstorm and written a really simple dart script and a html document.

the head of my html doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="scaffolded-by" content="https://github.com/google/stagehand">
    <title>Das bist du!</title>
   <script defer src="http://das-bist-du.com/main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
   <script defer src="http://das-bist-du.com/packages/browser/dart.js">    </script>
 </head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

the dart code:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math';

ButtonElement rndButton;
ImageElement rndImage;  
var images;
var rng;

void main() {
  rndButton = querySelector('#rndButton');
  rndImage = querySelector('#imgScreen');

  images = ['http://das-bist-du.com/onewebmedia/anN0MBo_700b.jpg', 'http://das-bist-du.com/onewebmedia/du1.jpg', 'http://das-bist-du.com/onewebmedia/du2.jpg', 'http://das-bist-du.com/onewebmedia/du3.jpg', 'http://das-bist-du.com/onewebmedia/du3.jpg', 'http://das-bist-du.com/onewebmedia/du4.jpg', 'http://das-bist-du.com/onewebmedia/du5.jpg', 'http://das-bist-du.com/onewebmedia/du6.jpg'];
  rndButton.onClick.listen(pickYou);
}
 void pickYou (Event e) {
  rng = new Random();
  setYou(rng.nextInt((images.length)));
}

void setYou (var rnd) {
  print(images[rnd].toString());
  rndImage.src =  (images[rnd].toString());
}
```

I know the code is not pretty and all, i was just testing things out. :)

Now i want to use both on a website, i uploaded the html page the code and the dart.js to the website and put the src in the html script tag.

When testing in Webstorm with Chromium it works. 
But the script dont run on the website. How can i use dart online on a website?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart doesn't run in any browser directly except Dartium (the Chomium based Dart development browser that includes the Dart VM).

When you run `pub build` in your project directory (where the `pubspec.yaml` is) then you get an output in the `build` sub-directory that can be uploaded to web servers for public use.

There is also a transformer available that optimizes the script tags when `pub build` is run. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_to_js_script_rewriter

Comment: So there is no way I can use the Dart vm online? I tried to convert my dart Code to js with dsrt2js , the result was 8000 lines of code, so I think I did something wrong. I will try the Pub build later thank you

Comment: `pub build` uses `dart2js` under the hood. Maybe the output wasn't minified. Dart has to include some code by default in addition to the code you wrote yourself because it provides lots of additional features for browser abstraction (like jQuery) and other stuff. Therefore you won't get 15 lines of JS even when the Dart example is just a "Hello World".

Comment: You can't use the Dart VM online. Dartium is not intended to be used in production and no other browser supports Dart directly. That was planned a while ago but these plans were dropped a year ago for various reasons.